# zend framework version trouble

Tags: php, zend-framework

am 100% sure I downloaded and extracted version 1.8 of ZF, but then when I go to console and typed "zf show version" it says am using 1.9.6, yes I do have 1.9.6 but it is "Compressed" and untouched, how could this be possible ?, I double checked my system variables, there's no evidence of ZF there. I also checked my php.ini file, it's pointed to the location of the extracted 1.8 ZF.. please help. this is my first attempt in using ZF

Comment: How did you download and install ZF? Have you previously installed the later version on your computer?

Comment: as far as I can recall sir, I didn't pursue learning ZF before, all I can see is a zipped 1.9.6..but then last night I downloaded 1.8 and installed it by just extracting it, and then pointing the include_path to the bin folder of the 1.8 version..that's all I did, I don't really know why it's showing 1.9 in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me guess, you are using xampp oder zend server community edition? Both Stacks are bringing their own Zend Framework version with them.

Comment: yes am using xampp, i just don't know why it got stuck with 1.9.6 ..now am using 1.10.4 and it still stuck with 1.9.6 via zend_tool

Comment: because xampp ZF version is in your path variable (and xampp has altough an ZF.BAT)

Comment: this didn't help it..but i chose it as an answer to avoid being warned again of not choosing an answer for my question..thanks anyway